# Show custom message for unauthorized page access on redirected page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using `onRequest()` to validate the access level of a user and if the user has the privilege to access the page then include the requested template. If he doesn't, I redirect to the last active page or default page. The last active page has been stored in `session` scope.

I am trying to show a message for unauthorized access on the redirected page.

Simplest solution will be to add a `url` parameter to the redirected page.

Is there any other approach for this?

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to forget about the last active page and send everyone to the default page. Otherwise you need message code on every page.

Answer (score 4):

Since you store the "last active" page in the session scope, you could easily store the "redirection message" in the session scope as well.

Problem with links that pull their state out of the session is that they become unstable when there is no session (timed out, for example). The next time the link gets reloaded (browser restore, for example), the page has no context to display.

Therefore, storing the state in the URL is not a bad thing. Either that or you go with the session and explicitly write your code so that it handles the "no session" condition sensibly.

---

EDIT: Note the comment by @Mark about the dangers of XSS. While that can be mitigated by proper use of `HtmlEditFormat()` and `URLEncodedFormat()`, there is a general danger of people abusing the feature to construct URLs that make your page show inappropriate messages. Using error codes instead of clear text messages in the URL is highly advisable. It also results in shorter URLs and it is internationalization-friendly.

Comment: I would add that passing an error "code" and then displaying a message from an array of messages based on the code is a "better practice" that simply passing the messages itself on the URL. When you pass something on the URL that is subsequently displayed on the page you open yourself up to XSS attacks.